# Call controller's function from another controller / Share data between controllers

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

For the moment, when I'm in a controller and that I want to call a function from another controller, I do this :

```
App.app.getControllerInstances()['App.controller.OtherController'].do_something();
```

Is seems a bit heavy to me, is there another (better) way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would use the getController method: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-getController

EG: `this.getApplication().getController('ControllerName').doSomething();`

Answer (score 11):

If you're not in the context of your Controller(for example in a callback function of some object), you can do this.

```
MyAppName.app.getController('ControllerName').doSomething();
```

Answer (score 7):

When using the MVC convention in Sencha Touch 2,  I would recommend the following when trying to call a method called 'SomeMethodInB' in 'ControllerB' from inside 'ControllerA':

> MyAppName.app.getController('ControllerB').

'MyAppName' is the name of the app you defined in the core app definition - typically in your app.js file.

According to the Sencha forums, the below is depreciated:

> this.getApplication().getController('ControllerB').SomeMethodInB();

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?158996

In fact the only way I can call the "this.getApplication()" method to even work is when calling it from my app definition file (app.js).