# Javascript - Sencha touch 2.1 - Calling an app.js level function returns "[object Object] has no method 'getLocalLoggedUserDetails'"

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have written a simple global function at the `app.js` level of my sencha touch 2.1 application.
Now, based on the clues found here on stack and from other sources, all that i have to do to call it from everywhere is something like

`TimeMobile.app.myGlobalFunction(params);`

the point is, it does not work and i get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getLocalLoggedUserDetails'

I tried to call the `launch()` function instead and that is working.
This is puzzling me more than before because at this point it's not a syntax problem.

I call the global function like this:

`var LoggedUserDetails = TimeMobile.app.getLoggedUserDetails(true);`

and my app.js is defined like this:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    models: [
        'LoginResponse'
    ],
    stores: [
        'LoginStore',
        'PlannedActivityListStore',
        'RemoteUserDetailsStore',
        'LocalUserDetailsStore'
    ],
    views: [
        'LoginView'
    ],
    name: 'TimeMobile',
    controllers: [
        'ctlLogin',
        'ctlPlannedActivities'
    ],

    launch: function() {
        //this.TimeMobile =this;
        TimeMobile.app.LoggedUser ='';
        TimeMobile.app.LoggedUserPsw ='';
        TimeMobile.app.AnagId = 'CTEL';
        TimeMobile.app.CurrentDate = new Date().toISOString();
        TimeMobile.app.LoggedUserDetails = TimeMobile.model.mdlUserDetails();

        Ext.create('TimeMobile.view.LoginView', {fullscreen: true});
    },

    getLoggedUserDetails: function(enabled) {
        if (enabled)
        {
            //var store= TimeMobile.app.LocalUserDetailsStore();
            //return store.getAt(0);
            console.log('called');
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

});
```

When I call `getLoadedUserDetails` with the syntax `TimeMobile.app.getLoadedUserDetails(true);` I get the error previously mentioned.
`TimeMobile.getLoadedUserDetails(true);` does not work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look with the article.

[Call controller's function from another controller / Share data between controllers][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10672241/1034986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome caching were preventing my app.js to be downloaded upon application refresh.

My bad.

To disable chrome caching, go to the console, click on the gear icon on the bottom-right corner and find the "disable cache" checkbox in the "General" tab.

**P.S.** *for the ones who -1ed without sayng anything about the question, have fun (on my profile you can find alot of questions or answer where you can have a bit more fun).*